# tengo un identificador de una base mysql alfanumérico y necesito identificar el mayor

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una tabla con un identificador que tiene el siguiente formato: `VET00000001 , VET00000002, VET00000003, etc`. Las letras van variando segun el tipo de dato (VET, END, VTI) y los numeros irían aumentando en uno con cada nueva fila pero según el tipo de dato, por ejemplo puedo tener `VET00000001 y END00000001`.

Necesito consultar cual es el mayor id ingresado según cada dato, ejemplo saber cual es el mayor id ingresado del tipo VET..

Alguien tiene idea como hacerlo? probe utilizando `MAX` y `LIKE` pero me devuelve `NULL`

Comment: Almacenas esos ID en una columna de qué tipo?, Además de eso muestra por favor la consulta que intentaste

Comment: @Aprendiz Gracias! estaba utilizando mal el LIKE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estaba bien utilizar `MAX` y `LIKE` pero estaba utilizando mal el LIKE.
Con esta consulta quedo andando:

```
SELECT MAX(id_inscripcion) FROM `inscripcion` WHERE id_inscripcion LIKE 'VET%'
```

Comment: No olvides en cuanto puedas, marcar tu respuesta como aceptada para indicar que tu duda fue resuelta